# What means "perfect major"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Regarding the context of this sentence:

*I’d put taking classes with great professors above picking the perfect major.*

What does the author mean with **perfect major**? I am not able to translate this.

Here is the [full text](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/i-could-start-over-heres-what-id-do-differently-joel-peterson)

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/major Definition 3 - Voting to close as General Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the article is on a career site, the likelihood is that the author means a college major that leads to a degree in an 'in demand' field, with which the graduate expects to obtain a quick job or a high salary but not always to have had a great education.

Comment: I clearly understand now the meaning in context. Thank you @Rache

Answer (score 2):

When studying at universities (at least in the Us and Canada), your major is the subject you take the most courses in (and your minor is the subject you take the second highest number of courses in. I, for example, majored in civil engineering with no minor.

Picking the "perfect major" means finding the perfect topic to specialise in for a bachelor degree based on interest and fit.

But I think this may be general reference.